# Menu location switcher - example code fails

Tags: menus, filters

Frustrated as to why even a WordPress sample code fails. Writing a simple plugin that will switch which menu I am displaying based on the user's logged-in state and role.  I am saving the present menu, in the event

The code area in question is as follow:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'MenuSelector' );

function MenuSelector( $args = '')
{ 
    $menu_name = 'primary';
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();  
    $menu_id = $locations[ $menu_name ] ;   
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($menu_id);
    $PrimaryMenu =  $menu['name'];

......
}
```

This is identical to the code suggested on the WordPress reference.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_object

Even so, the following error appears:

> Notice: Undefined index: primary in
>   /home/dskurth/public_html/wp-content/plugins/MenuSelector/main.php on
>   line 105.

**Line 105 is:  $menu_id = $locations[ $menu_name ] ;**

So basically it is saying that the definition of the menu name, ie: 'primary' is an undefined variable.  This is even after following the WordPress definition of the array returned by:

```
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

So, the code in the documentation assumes that the menu you're trying to get is set as the `primary` menu. If the menu you're trying to get isn't the one set as `primary`in Apperance -> Menus, this error will show. I suggest you try to work with their `name` or `slug` instead.